# Unresolved reference: viewModels (hilt)

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I already  have added dependency but still getting error

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

> Unresolved reference: viewModels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `fragment-ktx` and `activity-ktx`

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it also depends on how you want to use dependencies.

```
//to add the dependency on Fragment
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
```

```
//to add the dependency on the Activity
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0'
```