# Unresolved reference viewModels() Hilt

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have implemented all dependency provided on internet, but still not able to fix the issue. refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804803/unresolved-reference-viewmodels-hilt) and [this](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1498) link and other links on stackoverflow, but not able to resolve issue.

I am facing issue while creating instance of viewModel on activity, in fragment i am not facing any challenge.

Here is my App build gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'

    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1'
    //Retrofit - network calls
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.0'

    //Hilt - Dependency Injection
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")


    //Page lifecycle owners
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    def coroutines_version = "1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    //QR generation library
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'

 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}

Project build gradle :
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.5.1' apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

Code in activity :
[image]

Code in Fragment :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message when you hover over the red line `viewModels()`?

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati Unresolved reference: viewModels error message displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add activity-ktx dependency like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1', //you can change the version as needed/
```

Comment: still same error Unresolved reference: viewModels

Comment: @nileshbirhade
have you checked if the you're having the latest version?
also can you add this import in your activity: 
import androidx.activity.viewModels